# How to schedule my batch class on click on button in VF page

Tags: apex, visualforce

```
global class CreateAccountRecordsBatch implements Database.Batchable<sObject>{

   global String Query;
   global CreateAccountRecordsBatch(){

   }

   global Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext BC){
    Query='select id from Account limit 10';
      return Database.getQueryLocator(query);
   }

   global void execute(Database.BatchableContext BC, List<Account> scope){
     List<Account> accountList = new List<Account>();
     for(Account A : scope){
        Account objA = new Account(Name = 'Test');
        accountList.add(objA);
     }
     insert accountList;
    }

   global void finish(Database.BatchableContext BC){
   }
}

<apex:page controller="scheldulingjobs">
<apex:form >
<apex:page >
<apex:pageBlockSection >
<apex:pageBlockSection >
  <apex:commandButton value="create account"/>
  </apex:pageBlockSection>
  </apex:pageBlockSection>
  </apex:page>
  </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

I want to schedule my batch, so whenever command button is clicked it has to schedule the batch and generate test records.

Comment: i had created schelduled a job called createAccount,how can i call this schedule job in apex class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can execute your batch class with in command button action method in controller. so whenever you click on command button batch class will be executed. Please see below sample code for your reference.

sample code:

Page:

```
apex:commandButton value="create account" Action="{!callBatch}"
```

Controller:

```
public void callBatch()
{

 CreateAccountRecordsBatch c = new CreateAccountRecordsBatch();

 Database.executeBatch(c);

}
```

Comment: <apex:page controller="pagenan">
<apex:form >
<apex:page >


  <apex:commandButton value="create account"  action="{!callBatch}"/>

  
  </apex:page>
  </apex:form>
</apex:page>

Comment: public with sharing class pagenan {
static string s='sasa';
public void callBatch()
{
system.debug('dd'+s);
 //CreateAccountRecordsBatch c = new CreateAccountRecordsBatch();

 //Database.executeBatch(c);

}
}

Comment: what error you are getting

Answer (score 0):

Use scheduleBatch(batchable, jobName, minutesFromNow) System method.

`CreateAccountRecordsBatch obj = new CreateAccountRecordsBatch();
String sch = '0 0 13 * * ?';//runs every day at 1 PM.
system.scheduleBatch(obj,'Create Account Batch', sch);`

[developer guide reference](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_batch_interface.htm#apex_batch_scheduleBatch_section)